# java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /192.168.1.11:3000

Tags: android, webserver, okhttp

My first question here :)

I am trying to connect my localhost web server (port 3000) by POST request from my application in my **debug device** (which is connected via USB cable).
For the http requests I am using okhttp3 api.

My url:

```
public static final String localhostPrefix = "http://192.168.1.11:3000/";
```

When i am trying to create a new call, I am getting this error message:

```
W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /192.168.1.11:3000
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried pinging this server from the host?

Comment: Yes, via postman it worked!

Comment: try to listen on 127.0.0.1:3000